# Monorepo with Expo and Multiple Entry Points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, monorepo

I have two Expo (React Native) apps that share most of their code and are already in production. We are trying to move them to a monorepo directory structure as follows:

```
lerna.json
package.json
packages/
    mobile-1/
        app.json
        index.js
        package.json
    mobile-2/
        app.json
        index.js
        package.json
    mobile-common/
        src/
            ... actual app code ...
        index.js
        package.json
```

The way our setup works is that we export a function that starts the app from `mobile-common/index.js` and `mobile-{1,2}/index.js` are supposed to call this function with initialization parameters specific to each of them.

The problem with this setup is that `mobile-common` makes use of `react-native` and `expo` dependencies, which are also required by `exp` to start the React Native packager which causes certain issues at build time. We tried the following:

- Adding `mobile-common`, `expo` and `react-native` to the dependencies in  `mobile-{1,2}/package.json` and doing `lerna bootstrap`. This allows us to run the packager but mobile apps crash while building because they find duplicate dependencies.
- We never got yarn workspaces to work, either.
- `lerna bootstrap --hoist` also did not work.
- `npm link` also produced issues at build time with duplicate dependencies.

We really want to move to this kind of structure because our previous structure didn't easily allow us to run both apps side by side, and it is becoming increasingly necessary.

Thanks for helping us out!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup expo with a monorepo you can look at [my example here](https://github.com/Fried-Chicken/expo-monorepo).

Currently the expo packages must remain in the root package.json because of limitations with watchman not resolving symlinks properly.

Comment: This is nice, but I have no idea why all this code in expo-yarn-workspaces is needed.  Why is it so complicated?

I shudder at importing this custom code that I don't understand into my project.